My cookie can't be set through browser but from postman it is working fine
I want to set cookie from frontend but I can't able to set. It is working fine from postman but it can't be set from frontend. Please help me in this I was stucked from last few days.
const cookieOption = {
maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
httpOnly: true,
secure: true,
sameSite: 'None',
}
I had set this in cookie option.
But after this also from frontend I can't set the cookie.
